# Establishing set equivalence: Munkres exercise 1.7

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

An exercise in Munkres asks to write this set in terms of $\cup$, $\cap$, and $-$. The set I cannot figure out is:
$$F = \{x \mid x \in A \text { and } (x \in B \implies x \in C)\}.$$
Here is what I have done so far.
\begin{align*}
x \in A \text{ and } (x \in B \implies x \in C) & \iff x \in A \text{ and } (x \not \in B \text{ or } x \in C) \\
& \iff (x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in B) \text{ or } (x \in A \text{ and } x \in C) \\
& \iff (x \in A - B) \text{ or } (x \in A \cap C) \\
& \iff x \in (A \cap B)\cup (A - B).
\end{align*}
The solution to the problem, though, is
$$F = A - (B - C).$$
I cannot figure out why my solution is incorrect. In the first step, I used the material implication rule , $p \implies q \equiv \neg p \lor q$. In the second, I used the fact that $\wedge$ distributes over $\lor$. All of my steps seem valid, but these resulting sets are not equivalent.

Comment: Have you tried making a Venn diagram for this?

Comment: You have a typo in your last line. Otherwise, the solutions are equivalent.

Comment: You have made a mistake in your last step. Please consider looking at it again. Then the answer follows.

Comment: The last line should say $x \in (A \cap C) \cup (A - B)$. There is a typo here. But this isn't equivalent to $A - (B - C)$. I can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, except that after “$(x\in A\setminus B)\vee(x\in A\cap C)$”, you should have written “$\iff x\in(A\cap C)\cup(A\setminus B)$”. And you can check that$$(A\cap C)\cup(A\setminus B)=A\setminus(B\setminus C).$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand this step. Am I incorrect that $\lor$ generally translates to union, signifying inclusive or? I must be missing something.

Comment: Yes, $\vee$ translates to union. If $x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C)$ the $x\in A$ and $x\notin B\setminus C$. Note that$$x\notin B\setminus C\iff x\notin B\vee x\in C.$$If $x\notin B$, then $x\in A\setminus B$. And, if $x\in C$, then $x\in A\cap C$. Therefore, $x\in(A\cap C)\cap(A\setminus B)$. I've just proved that$$A\setminus(B\setminus C)\subset(A\cap C)\cap(A\setminus B).$$The proof of the reverse inclusion is similar.

Comment: Everything you've written here makes complete sense to me, and I appreciate it. Where I still remain confused, though, is why if $\lor$ translates to union, my final step is incorrect, since it surely is.

Comment: I wrote in my answer that your final step is incorrect and that you should have written $(A\cap C)\cap(A\setminus B)$ instead of $(A\cap B)\cap(A\setminus B)$.

Comment: I understand that step: that was a bad typo on my part. But why is it $(A \cap C) \cap (A \setminus B)$ instead of $(A \cap C) \cup (A \setminus B)$ if the only thing we're changing is converting $\vee$ to $\cup$?

Comment: It's not your fault if you don't understand it . **I** made a typo and wrote (twice!) $\cap$ instead of $\cup$. I've edited my answer. Sorry about that. Unfortunately, I cannot edit my first comment.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$\{x: x \in B \implies x \in C\}$ is $B^\complement \cup (B \cap C)$ ( either $x \notin B$ and the implication is voidly true, or $x \in B$ is true but then also $x \in C$. You can check that is equals $(B-C)^\complement$, because the only way to *refute* the implication is to have $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$, or $x \in B-C$. Intersect this with $A$ (as in the question: $x \in A$ should also hold, so we have an intersection) and we get $A- (B - C)$ as expected (using $X \cap Y^\complement = X-Y$ ).

Answer (score 1):

$$x \in A \land (x \in B \Rightarrow x \in C) \Leftrightarrow  x \in A \land (x \notin B \lor x \in C) \Leftrightarrow  x \in A \land \neg (x \in B \land x \notin C)$$
And now on right hand there is $A\setminus(B\setminus C)$.